# ymaps Удаление маршрутов из мультимаршрута

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Каким образом можно из полученного мультимаршрута

```
var myMultiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({...})
```

убрать все маршруты, кроме нужного?
Просто обойти полученные маршруты могу в событии

```
myMultiRoute.model.events
    .add("requestsuccess", function (event) {
                        var routes = event.get("target").getRoutes();
                        for (var i = 0, l = routes.length; i < l; i++) {...}
```

А как можно сделать, чтобы на карте был отображен только нужный из всех полученных маршрутов? Суть - из полученного массива выбираю самый короткий маршрут. Его и надо отобразить. Раньше пользовался просто

```
ymaps.route(markers, {})
```

но теперь почему-то этим способом не учитываются платные дороги. Т.е. возвращаемый маршрут теперь не самый короткий.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать через [опции мультимаршрута](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute-docpage/#multiRouter.MultiRoute__param-options).

```js
// Скрывает все нитки маршрутов.
myMultiRoute.options.set('routeVisible', false);
// Показывает нитку активного маршрута.
myMultiRoute.options.set('routeActiveVisible', true);

myMultiRoute.setActiveRoute(myFindShortest(myMultiRoute.getRoutes()));
```

Comment: По предложенному варианту все получилось. Спасибо

Comment: Можете пометить ответ как правильный (галочка слева от ответа), чтобы следующим людям с таким вопрос было проще найти ответ